# JOptionPane Listing numbers

Tags: java, computer-science

So im confused with this question its baffling me right now. This is the question:

> "Ask the user to input a starting number and an ending number.  Printout all the number and its squared value in a table."

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class P4_1
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String response_1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the starting number: ");
      int start_number = Integer.parseInt(response_1);
      String response_2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the ending number: ");
      int end_number = Integer.parseInt(response_2);

      int set = start_number;

      while(start_number > end_number);
      {
         set++;
      }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, set);

      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to run the program again? ");

   }
}
```

Comment: So, I'm confused with you question too

Comment: What is your question. What is troubling you? Understanding of the question?

Comment: yeah understanding the question and what i need to do and how to list numbers

Answer (score 1):

> "Ask the user to input a starting number and an ending number. Printout all the number and its squared value in a table."

The question wants you to prompt the user twice with each time prompting for an integer via JOptionPane.

So if the user enters 3 and 5, print out the squares of 3 to 5:

```
i.e: 9 16 25
```